# ActionBar in android at bottom

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to put an action bar with 4 clickable entities, on the bottom of the activity. I should be able to associate each of the 4 entities/buttons with intents. Can anyone please tell me the xml file and the java code for this. I am not able to find this anywhere.

Comment: [Android design docs suggest you don't use a bottom tab bar](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html)

Comment: Only contextual actions can go in the bottom action bar. Like save, edit, delete etc.

Comment: Thanks for that info. Yes..i did research on that and now I have reverted to putting them on the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a [SplitActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) but in general it is recommended that the ActionBar be at the top and contactual actions go in the bottom bar.

Alternatively you can try playing with the gravity layout parameter as shown [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.LayoutParams.html), though I have not tried this and would advise against it.